# Making new list of Object Attribute then calling each attribute with a incrementing int variable

Tags: c#, list, class, indexoutofrangeexception

This might be a stupid question but I am new to C# coding and object-oriented programming. I'm trying to assign strings to a Class attribute while using an incrementing variable called "x".
But after increment x once, C# tells me "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range".

I just not getting it, it should be able to create a lot of clients with this.

```
        int x = 0;
        private void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<Client> newClient = new List<Client>();  //creates a variable called "newClient" which is a list of Client object
            newClient.Add(new Client());                  // calling a constructor to create a Client Object
            newClient[x].Name = textBoxName.Text;         //newclient[0]
            newClient[x].Address = textBoxAddress.Text;
            newClient[x].Birthday = textBoxBirthDay.Text;
            newClient[x].Gender = textBoxGender.Text;
            newClient[x].PhoneNumber = textBoxPhoneNumber.Text;
            newClient[x].Income = textBoxIncome.Text;

            string Output = newClient[x].Name + " " + newClient[x].Address + " " + newClient[x].birthday + " " + newClient[x].Gender + " " + newClient[x].PhoneNumber + " " + newClient[x].Income;
            labelOutput.Text += Output + "\n";
            x++;
        }
```

Comment: You are creating a new list each time `buttonSubmit_Click` is invoked. You probably want to make `newClient` a member variable.

Comment: as you're creating the list again and again, it will allways have just a single item, while you increment `x`. So after the first call to your event-handler, `x` will be 1. When invoking the handler a second time, `x` is still one, but as you create a new list with only a single item, `newClient[1]` throws.

Answer (score 0):

I edit your function to works as you want !!!!

```
    List<Client> newClient = new List<Client>();  //creates a variable called "newClient" which is a list of Client object
    private void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var tobeInsertedClient = new Client()
        {
            Name = textBoxName.Text,
            Address = textBoxAddress.Text,
            Birthday = textBoxBirthDay.Text,
            Gender = textBoxGender.Text,
            PhoneNumber = textBoxPhoneNumber.Text,
            Income = textBoxIncome.Text
        };
        newClient.Add(tobeInsertedClient);


        string Output = tobeInsertedClient.Name + " " + tobeInsertedClient.Address + " " + tobeInsertedClient.birthday + " " + tobeInsertedClient.Gender + " " + tobeInsertedClient.PhoneNumber + " " + tobeInsertedClient.Income;
        labelOutput.Text += Output + "\n";
    }
```

You can Initialize an object with brackets {} and then you can use it in the scope you want :D

Comment: This doesn't solve the primary problem, as the list is still recreated each time the button is clicked.

Comment: @PMF The example has local scope list not global !!! I edit the my answer, but we do not have the big scope of his solution.

Comment: True, but it's quite obvious that the OP wants to add a new element each time the button is pressed, otherwise this doesn't do anything useful.